# Code to store indices of occurrences doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

In the program that I'm writing, I currently have a for-loop that goes through an array, `num[5]`, and checks to see if there are any 1's in that array, which looks like:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    if (num[i] == 1)
        counter++;
```

This works successfully, but I'm now trying to go through the array and see what the indices of the 1's in the program are.  So, if I have `01001`, I want to make an array that holds the positions of the 1's.  The following is what I've tried so far:

```
int b[counter];
for (int k = 0; k <= counter; k++) {
   for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (num[i] == 1) {
          b[k] = i;
      }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't produce the desired result. When I type the string in, say `1001`, I get `444`.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: First off, you have a flaw in your second code. `int b[counter];` will result an array of `0` to `counter-1`. You later try to access `b[k]` when `k` might be equal to `counter` because you used the comparison of `k <= counter` in your first loop (notice the equals sign) this would result in a memory access violation.

Comment: C's arrays start with index 0 and not 1. What may seem successful is actually undefined since you are accessing `num[5]` which is out of bounds. Accessing `num[0]` to `num[4]` is right.

Answer (score 1):

For each value of `k`, for each occurrence of a `1`, you're setting `b[k]` to the index of the `1`. Thus each `b[k]` will have the index of the last `1`.

Try:

```
int b[counter];
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
   if (num[i] == 1) {
       b[k++] = i;
   }
}
```

So, whenever it gets a `1`, it assigns `b[k]` to the index and then increases `k`.

Then you should also use `k`, not `counter`, when trying to print out `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this part of your code.

```
int b[counter];
for (int k = 0; k <= counter; k++) {
   **for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (num[i] == 1) {
          b[k] = i;
      }**
    }
}
```

Suppose you get a `1` at the index `1` of the array as in `01001`. You assign `b[k] = 1;`
This is perfectly valid. But as the loop continues you get another `1` at the index `4`. Thus the command `b[k] = 4;` is again executed.
Note that your value of `k` is constant in both the statements and hence you get the array b as `44`.

So what you need to do is break the inner for loop as soon as you get a `1`.

Here is the modified code. You also need to keep a track of the iterator `i` and I have done that here using the variable- `new_pos  // new position`.

```
int b[counter];
int new_pos=0;  //to keep track of the iterator
for (int k = 0; k <= counter; k++) {
   for (i = new_pos; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (num[i] == 1) {
          b[k] = i;
          new_pos = i+1;
          break;
      }
    }
}
```

The code provided by [Dukeling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling) is also perfect, but I am just giving another way to make your own code work.